# What is the difference between Google Checkout & Wallet?

Tags: google-checkout, android-pay

I just got an email from Google informing me that they will be shuttering Google Checkout and that I should switch to Google Wallet. This confuses me because I started my Google digital goods shopping cart 6 months ago I was under the impression that Checkout was already dead. Numerous news articles and Wikipedia all state that Checkout was merged into Wallet back in 2011. Many Google support pages even use the terms Google Checkout and Google Wallet interchangeably, and they all have a Google Wallet logo at the top.

My question is simple, is this [api that I am using](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Subscriptions) one of the ones being discontinued. If so, is there a Wallet (or other) alternative and a good way to transition?

When I went to [this page](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/) and clicked "Sign up", the very first step it asked me to do is go to the [Merchant Center](https://checkout.google.com/sell/settings?section=Financials) and enter my credentials. Of course I have already entered my credentials there when I signed up for Google Wallet Checkout 6 months ago, furthermore this page also has a giant red notice telling me this service is being discontinued. Am I going insane or is this outrageously confusing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the API that [you linked](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Subscriptions) will be retired.

Google will not be providing a replacement product. Your transition will consist of either swapping Checkout with a non-Google provider or integrating Google Wallet Instant Buy or Google Wallet for digital goods. You will need to see which of the three can fit your checkout/payments model.

The API that you linked was Checkout's subscription capability. Google Wallet for digital goods supports subscriptions so you may want to take a look at that.

[This page](https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/3080449?hl=en&ref_topic=3080448) contains a lot of really good detail regarding Checkout retirement. I think it can answer all/most of your questions.

And yes, I do agree the entire ecosystem of documentation around the various Google payment related services is more confusing than need be. :)

Comment: A year or so later, I'm not sure if this is the case... Wallet for Digital Goods is alive and well, though confusingly, the developer portal is branded checkout... where the QA sandbox is wallet.